# Is it possible to scroll to a particular subview inside a container view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextfield, uicontainerview

I have a container view created in a xib, I have added various textfields to that container view, In a case when the user reaches that view controller I want the container view to automatically scroll to a particular textfield and focus on it.

Note that I am not using scroll view as of and I am trying to know is there a way to do it without using UIScrollView

Answer (score 0):

There is no ability to make a UIView scroll in of itself. I would recommend using either a scroll view or a table view. If you decide to use a table view, you would have your textfields in individual cells, then you could do something like this to scroll:

```
//Scroll to 4th text field
NSIndexPath *indexToScrollTo = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0];
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexToScrollTo 
                 atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop 
                         animated:YES];
```

In a scroll view, you would set the content offset to scroll to a particular y position. Here's an examle:

```
//Scroll down by 50
self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,50);
```

Answer (score 0):

yes,you can do it by using `TableViewController`. it automatically focus on the text fields and automatically scroll up when keyboard appears.